# How to getView of fragment extended with another class?

Tags: android, android-fragments

the title is a bit confusing, but I don't know what to write.

I'm using a library to expose a Sliding Tutorial for the start of my app ([SlidingTutorial](https://github.com/Cleveroad/SlidingTutorial-Android)). The problem is that I need to find a view in the fragment with findViewById but I need to derivate this call from the view of the fragment. I should use the method onCreateView but as I said in the title, my fragment need to extend from TutorialSupportFragment (despite of Fragment), so If I override the method onCreateView, some components from the library failed to load.

Is there a way to use this onCreateView without destroying the extended method?

```
public class CustomTutorialFragment extends TutorialSupportFragment implements OnTutorialPageChangeListener, CustomTutorialMvpView {

...
```

I need to run this:

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(getLayoutResId(), container, false);

        btNext = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btNext);
        btSkip = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btSkip);

        btNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                nextPage();
            }
        });

        btSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                skipTutorial();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

This is the error, which I think that the problem is that I can override the method without breaking the previous one created by the library.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.dummy.carrefour.mvp, PID: 24342
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.dummy.carrefour.mvp/com.dummy.carrefour.mvp.ui.tutorial.TutorialActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
       at com.cleveroad.slidingtutorial.TutorialImpl.onViewCreated(TutorialImpl.java:97)
       at com.cleveroad.slidingtutorial.TutorialSupportFragment.onViewCreated(TutorialSupportFragment.java:146)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1314)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1528)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1595)
       at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:758)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2363)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2149)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.optimizeAndExecuteOps(FragmentManager.java:2103)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2013)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:388)
       at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:607)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1248)
       at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6699)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2629)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2727) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Comment: Can you show the code because it's difficult to understand without it.

Comment: Posted, sorry. Take a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options.

First one is to call `super.onCreateView()` and perform actions using the returned `View`:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    // Perform necessary actions
    Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
    return view;
}
```

Second option is to override `onViewCreated()`.

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    // Perform necessary actions
    Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
}
```